# Android DateFormat behaving unpredictably

Tags: android, locale, time-format

In the UI of my app, I format timestamps as follows:

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
updated.setText(format.format(message.getTimestamp()));
```

(If it matters—yes, I obtain the instance every time I need to format a timestamp.)

However, behavior is somewhat unpredictable: I have two devices, one running Android 7.1.2, the other running Android 4.4.4. Both have the same settings: Display language is English (US), keyboard layout is Lithuanian, time format is 24-hour.

On the 7.1.2 device, timestamps are usually displayed as expected (e.g. `19:42`). However, sporadically they display as `7:42 pm` instead. When that happens, it is consistent across all timestamps, i.e. I never get a mix of formats. Also, this appears to happen when the device has just booted.

The 4.4.4 device consistently displays the wrong time format, i.e. `7:42 pm`.

How can I get time to consistently display in the same format the user has selected in Android’s system settings?

Comment: Annoying. What does `Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT)` return in either case? `DateFormat.getTimeInstance(int)` uses this.

Comment: The way I read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getTimeInstance(int)), `getTimeInstance()` should not respect a 24 hour setting on the phone. However, if the default locale implies a 24 hour clock for time format, this should be respected.